# how to print object from RESTful web service using jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, pug

I am trying to print something from a RESTful web service but it comes out like this.

```
{
"
i
d
"
:
"
e
9
7
f
e
6
2
0
-
1
6
5
6
-
1
1
e
5
-
9
5
5
e
-
2
7
1
a
3
8
c
2
6
f
3
2
"
,
"
d
a
t
a
"
:
{
"
n
a
m
e
"
:
"
d
e
p
o
s
i
t
c
h
e
q
u
e
"
}
```

What I am hoping for instead is something like this:

```
1. deposit cheque
```

I am not too sure if it is a problem with my java script or jade but here are both.

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

```
    request({
    url: url, //URL to hit
    qs: {from: 'blog example', time: +new Date()}, //Query string data
    method: 'GET', //Specify the method  
    headers: { //We can define headers too
        'Content-Type': 'MyContentType',
        'Custom-Header': 'Custom Value'
    }
    }, function(error, response, body){
      if(error) {
          res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: []});
      } else {
          res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: body });
      }

});
```

Here is my jade:

```
ul
  for item in data
    li= item
  else
    li sorry, no items!
```

How can I modify this to print out what I want?

Comment: I think you need to call `JSON.parse(body)` on the `data` before passing it to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try `res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: JSON.stringify(body) });`

Comment: Is your case similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301258/how-to-render-json-object-in-jade-and-loop-through-results ?

Comment: I've also looked at that. They seem similar, except I am not making a variable, I am retrieving it from a RESTful web service.

Comment: Can I shot you the object I am sending to client side? 
{"id":"e97fe620-1656-11e5-955e-271a38c26f32","data":{"name":"deposit cheque"}