# Processing variables send with nodejs inside jade

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, pug

I have a script sending a matrix, something like `[[1,2,3,4], [7,6,5,4], [2,3,4,5]]`. When I send it using `res.send(JSON.stringify(dataArray));` and display it in jade using `h1#results` I do indeed see the format is correct.

However I would like to use this data inside the google charts. My intuition would say to present the data like this: `data.addRows = results;`. This is however not the case because jade doesn't understand that I mean the variable send.

I suspect I do not understand some basic principle behind jade. I understand that most of jade/html is fixed and that only code within "script" tags get executed but as far as I can see all code inside google's `function drawChart() {)` is within a script tag.

**EDIT**

My new ajax script:

```
    $(function() {
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        var parameters = { search: $(this).val()};
        $.get('/seraching', parameters, function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
            console.log('parsing json');
            var chartData = (data);
            console.log(chartData[0])
            drawChart(chartData, parameters.search);
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Don't you get the results from `html#results`, parse it, and then pass it as an argument to `drawchart`?

Comment: How would I do this? I mean I don't usually deal with jade/html. `script.
    var results = html#results` is not right.

Comment: So you're just trying to render json in your jade? Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301258/how-to-render-json-object-in-jade-and-loop-through-results

Comment: I do send it as an object. My JSON.stringify is just to confirm it for myself. When I use this: `data.addRows = !{results};` it says "Unexpected token ';'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there several issues at play here. First, using Express and Jade to deliver a processed template, using AJAX with a search parameter to get some data, and using an Express route to send some data based on the search parameter you send it.

Initially you want Express and Jade to set up the main page:

**main.jade**

```
html
    head
        script(src='googlechart.js')
        script(src='myJS.js')
    body
        title Title
        h1 Heading
        input("type='text', id='search'")
        button("id='submit'")
```

So here we ensure that Google chart is loaded as well as the JS that will contain your AJAX call. I've also included the text box for the search parameter.

In your Express app you would render the page like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render("main.jade");
});
```

**myJS.js**

First set up the chart object. Then, when the submit button is clicked, use the value of the search field in the ajax data property. Once the promise is resolved, display the results.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.DataTable();
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var param = $('#search').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getdata',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { search: param }
    }).done(function (data) {

        // note that jQuery automatically parses JSON for you
        chart.addRows(data);
    });
});
```

But! In order to do this you need to set up a route in Express to handle the AJAX call which would look like:

```
app.get('/getdata', function (req, res) {
    var param = req.param('search');

    // filter data by search param

    res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

So, you only need Jade once to set up the main template. It's the Express routes that you need to deliver the JSON data when you submit an AJAX request.

Hope that's a better answer :) Oh, there might be a couple of typos in here because I've not used Express for a while, but I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Comment: Thank you for the revised answer. As of now I haven't gotten it to work because of problems with loading google charts in a JS file instead of a jade file. I will work on this more later today and let you know if I run into trouble or when it works. I definitely will accept the answer once it does!

Comment: No worries, @SecondLemon. Best of luck.

Comment: I kinda have something working. The problem however now seems to be Google Charts itself. I have posted my "myJS.js" in my question. The drawChart(data, subtitle) works so far that the subtitle gets changed but the data does not get incorporated in the table. However I might have to open up a new question for this as the subject has changed a lot now.

Comment: Got it working! However I altered the code quite a lot. I'm still having all Google Chart code in the index.jade file. The most important thing I had missing was `drawChart(chartData, parameters.search);` located in the client-side javascript. This is the way I needed to pass along new variables to the jade file. It is quite a lot of code to post here without creating chaos so if anyone would like more information please let me know.